# How can you compute the smallest number of queens that can be placed to attack each uncovered square?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

This is a variant question from the Elements of Programming Interviews and doesn't come with a solution.

How can you compute the smallest number of queens that can be placed to attack each uncovered square?

Comment: Is the board empty? What size is it?

Comment: Yes the board is empty and the board size is n x n where n can be any value.

Comment: Upper bound for nxn board is n.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is about finding a minimal dominating set in a graph (the queen graph in your case http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QueenGraph.html), this more general problem is NP-Hard. Even if this reduction (on this specific kind of graphs) is unlikely to be NP-Hard, you may expect to not be able to find any efficient (polynomial) algorithm and indeed as up today nobody find one.

As an interview question, I think an acceptable answer would be a backtracking algorithm. You can add small improvements like always stop the search if you already put (n-2)-queens on the board.

For more information and pseudo-code of the algorithm and also more sophisticated algorithms I would suggest to read:

Fernau, H. (2010). minimum dominating set of queens: A trivial programming exercise?. Discrete Applied Mathematics, 158(4), 308-318.
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X09003722

Comment: Interesting - I was thinking about the problem as a set cover problem (each queen covers a set of locations) rather than a dominating set problem, but I really like this setup and approach!

Comment: If n is in binary, then I'm not aware of any argument that the problem should even be in [DSPACE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSPACE)(O(2^(input_length))). ​ If n is in [unary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_numeral_system), then there is a [F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FP_(complexity))P[/poly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P/poly) algorithm for the problem (just hardcode solutions), so the problem is unlikely to be NP-hard. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Giving more thoughts into this I agree with you the unary n problem on this specific problem is unlikely to be NP-Hard. I will edit the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is probably exhaustive searching with 1,2,3... queens until you find a solution. If you take the symmetries of the board into account you will only need ~10^6 searches to confirm that 4 queens is not enough (at that point you could use the same search until you find a solution for 5 queens or alternately, use a greedy algorithm for 5 queens to find a solution faster).